# Deep Q-Learning with large number of actions

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn

I'm using DQN with large number of actions in [0, 10000, step = 1000]. This means I have an action space of size 11 (including 0 and 10000). Action space is still discrete. My problem is that, instead of choosing sequence of best actions, DQN is selecting **zero** as best action at every training epoch, which is not desired. At the starting of training exploration rate is one, as training goes on it decreases by 0.99. Any help in this is appreciated.

```
import random
from collections import deque
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model, model_from_json
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import sgd
import os
class DQNAgent:
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=2000) # memory size
        self.gamma = 0.95    # discount rate
        self.epsilon = 1.0  # exploration rate
        self.epsilon_min = 0.01 # minmun exploration rate
        self.epsilon_decay = 0.99 # exploration decay
        self.learning_rate = 0.001 # learning rate
        self.model = self._build_model()

    def _build_model(self):
        # Neural Net for Deep-Q learning Model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear'))
        model.compile(loss='mse',
                      optimizer=sgd(lr=self.learning_rate))
        return model

    def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    def act(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
            return random.randrange(self.action_size)
        act_values = self.model.predict(state)
        return np.argmax(act_values[0])  # returns action

    def replay(self, batch_size):
        minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
        for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
            target = reward
            if not done:
                target = (reward + self.gamma *
                          np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0]))
            target_f = self.model.predict(state)
            target_f[0][action] = target
            self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
```

Comment: An action space of 11 discrete actions is not very large, should not be a problem for DQN. Likely something else is wrong in your implementation, so more details could help.

Comment: I can make action space more wider using the **step** parameter. If step=100, then action space is of size 1000.

Comment: Yes, but your current problem is clearly not caused by the size of the action space. You may have a *potential* problem later on. Which do you want to ask about - your actual problem now, or the potential problem later?

Comment: ya, you are right. My problem is not related to the size of the action space.

Comment: My DQN algorithm is choosing **zero** as a best action out of N discrete actions. After digging the steps, I noted that Q value for the action zero is always high and that's why DQN is selecting it as a best action. So how can I avoid this. Please see the agent code in the edited question.

Comment: The error is probably not in the agent.

Comment: Looking through your code, my best guesses would be state representation issues or Q-learning stability. Are you normalising state vector in any way? Or are the values naturally in a low range (e.g. $[-1, 1]$). Have you tried increasing the batch size or adding a frozen *target* network?

Comment: I'm not normalizing the state values. Range for state values are [0, 50000]. I have tried batch size with 32, 64, 100, but getting same result. Not tried frozen target network. Don't have any experience of it. Any good reference to this is appreciated.